# SpriteKit: better way to temporarily change velocity on sprite?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

Let's say node A is moving with an original velocity vector of (0, 9.8). After a collision with node B, node A should move backwards temporarily, say with a vector of (0, -2),  but after 0.2 seconds, resume its original velocity. In other words, node A should simulate the effects of a bump from node B before continuing its original trajectory.

This needs to happen in four directions, so we cannot rely on gravity (which only works in one direction).

We plan to do something like this:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact!) {
        let collision:UInt32 = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask)

        let dx = nodeB?.physicsBody?.velocity.dx
        let dy = nodeB?.physicsBody?.velocity.dy

        nodeB.runAction(                
            SKAction.sequence([
                SKAction.runBlock {
                    nodeB?.physicsBody?.applyImpulse( CGVectorMake(0, -2.0))
                },
                SKAction.waitForDuration(0.2)
            ]),
            completion: {
                nodeB?.physicsBody?.velocity.dx = dx
                nodeB?.physicsBody?.velocity.dy = dy
            }
        )
```

}

However, this seems messy. Is there a better way to do this with Swift?

Comment: Dunno about you, but even though I don't remember what applyImpulse does, this code is perfectly readable to me on first read.

1. Store the velocity in the x and y directions
2. Apply an impulse (change in acceleration) 
3. Wait 2 seconds
4. When done, reset the velocity back to the initial conditions

In my opinion, this is readable code. Don't worry and get on with it!

Comment: Thanks. Actually, we can't get the code to compile. Keep getting this error: Could not find an overload for 'runAction' that accepts the supplied arguments. If we empty the runBlock, the code compiles fine. Any clues?

Comment: I think runAction does not accept a completion closure. I cannot be sure because I haven't touched sprite kit in a while.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good idea to use intermediate variables when you have complex code.

```
let dx = nodeB?.physicsBody?.velocity.dx
let dy = nodeB?.physicsBody?.velocity.dy

let waitAction = SKAction.waitForDuration(0.2)

let runAction = SKAction.runBlock({ () -> Void in
    nodeB?.physicsBody?.applyImpulse( CGVectorMake(0, -2.0))
    return
})

let sequenceAction = SKAction.sequence([runAction,waitAction])

nodeB?.runAction(sequenceAction, completion: { () -> Void in
    nodeB?.physicsBody?.velocity.dx = dx!
    nodeB?.physicsBody?.velocity.dy = dy!
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a tip: I've noticed strange physics-engine breaks (NOT crashes, but physics got *corrupted* somehow) if I modified physicsBody.velocity *directly*.

Update method **should be used** for this.

Comment: It seems to be OK inside a SKNode.runAction/SKAction block